# Extension of class / Compiler-error

Tags: java, oop

Please take a look at the following classes:

```
public class Person {
  public void whatAreYou(){
    System.out.println("Person");
  }
}

public class Student extends Person {
  public void whatAreYou(){
    System.out.println("Student");
  }
}
```

When I try to call,

```
Person p = new Student();
p.whatAreYou();
```

my compiler tells me:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

I assume that this means that the method whatAreYou() isn't found here, but I don't understand that. It must be allowed to write `Person p = new Student()`since `Student`is an extension of `Person`. So, when we call `p.whatAreYou()` while running the programm, java should call the method whatAreYou() in the class Student. But the compiler already doesn't accept the reference here as it seems, although both methods even have the same name in their individual classes.

Can somebody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: Show us full codes.

Comment: Re-compile your whole project and maybe clean the cache of your IDE.

Comment: There are no full codes, it's an old exam question, and that is all what was given to us.

Comment: @AndyTurner i made a mistake anyways. does the `IO` works properly? its no standard java class

Comment: @Julian you said that you tried to compile the code and it gave you an error. So there must be more code because what you posted isn't complete code that can be compiled.

Comment: The code you've given us compile fine, assuming an `IO` class with a static `println` method. Please provide a [mcve], and be clear about where you're getting the error.

Comment: It's the whole code over there, as I said. That's what I tried to compile. Sorry for the "IO"-thing, it's just part of the tools we use at our university. It's the same as "System.out.println".

Comment: Anyway, I just found that I had a typo in it, that's what caused the problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler says : `cannot find symbol`, it means the class or method is unreachable, or doesn't exist.

In that case, it is the `IO` class that is concerned, and you should replace it by System.out, which is the default output for java program

Your code should be :

```
public class Person {
    public void whatAreYou(){
        System.out.println("Person");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Student extends Person {
    public void whatAreYou(){
        System.out.println("Student");
    }
}
```

And this will work perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the below code is in Student.java, this works just as expected.

```java
class Person {
  public void whatAreYou(){
    System.out.println("Person");
  }
}

public class Student extends Person {
  public void whatAreYou(){
    System.out.println("Student");
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Person p = new Student();
    p.whatAreYou();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it just says that the question doesn't make sense at the moment, really. That's more appropriate for comments -I know you can't comment now, but that doesn't make it appropriate to add an answer.

Comment: Please read this meta discussion about "your code works" answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable